# What's the simplest way to subtract all elements of one list from another list?

Tags: python

Given `list1` = `[1,2,2,3]`, `list2` = `[1,2]`, what's the simplest way to subtract all element of list2 from list1 to get list `list3` = `[2,3]`

It seems sum work well for two lists but subtraction doesn't.

To clarify: Order doesn't matter. L2 is a subset of L1. Duplicates need to be kept. Therefore can't use `set`.

```
>>> [1,2,2,3]+[1,2,3]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

>>> [1,2,2,3]-[1,2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Comment: What would a negative list element mean?  `[] - [1]`?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `+` _concatenates_ the lists

Comment: How could you add or subtract two lists of dissimilar length? If the length of both the lists would be same, then you might convert the lists to numpy array & perform addition, subtraction or whatever operation you like.

Comment: @timgeb I'm not sure that's a good dupe.  The answers there all seem to rely on `set` and don't preserve the multiplicity of the lists.  If anything, this might be `list((Counter(l1) - Counter(l2)).elements())`, but that won't preserve order.

Comment: I think you can use `remove` in this situation.  The `set` doesn't work here.  Try this instead: `[list1.remove(i) for i in list2]` `list1`

Comment: OP doesnt want to get the difference between 2 lists, this doesn't appear to be a dup

Comment: @scottboston that won't work because it removes both instances of `2`

Comment: @roganjosh `remove` removes the first instance of a value. Per docstring "L.remove(value) -> None -- remove first occurrence of value."

Comment: But, at best, it seems like an exploit of the OP's data rather than an approach that can be extrapolated. Why should concat add to the end but subtract take from the start, @scottboston

Comment: Sorry folks, given all these discussion, i still don't get what's the simplest way to get l3, if l2 is subset of l1. L.remove()is the closet one i could think of, but how can I move more than one element at a time? (if not using iteration) L.remove([lst]) doesn't work

Comment: @SoPia You haven't defined what you want the operation to do very well.  Does order matter?  Which side of the list are items being removed from? What happens if the right hand list contains more of some item than the left hand list?

Comment: Order doesn't matter. L2 is a subset of L1. Duplications needs to be kept

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `remove`:

```
list1 = [1,2,2,2,3]
list2 = [1,2,2]

[list1.remove(i) for i in list2] 
list1
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
```

#### Update without list comprehension, using standard for loops.

```
for i in list2:
    list1.remove(i)
list1
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
```

Comment: A follow up question not so relevant to the original problem. Why directly run "list.remove(i) for i in list2" in terminal without the [ ] generate me an error? 

>>> list1 = [1,2,2,2,3]
>>> list2 = [1,2,2]
>>> [list1.remove(i) for i in list2]
[None, None, None]
>>> list1
[2, 3]
>>> list1 = [1,2,2,2,3]
>>> list.remove(i) for i in list2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    list.remove(i) for i in list2
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Oh... you the [] denotes list comprehension which is a way of doing a loop.  To re-write that not using list comprehension will be as follows:  `for i in list2:` `list1.remove(i)`

Comment: in python shell, i input:  list1.remove(i) for i in list2, without the [], it returns a syntax error.  just curious why

Comment: @SoPia Yes, without the [] it is not a valid python command, you need to re-write it as I have updated in this answer.

Comment: [Here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), this can help you! List comprehension can be tricky with beginners :)

Comment: The OP wants a new list returned, `list3`—modifying `list1` instead isn't the quite same thing and may be unacceptable.

Comment: Then you could `list3 = list1.copy()` and use the same syntax on list3.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
list2 = [1, 2, 2]

counts = Counter(list2)
result = [l for l in list1 if counts.get(l, 0) == 0 or counts.subtract((l,))]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 3]
```

The list comprehension is *equivalent* to:

```
result = []
for l in list1:
    if counts.get(l, 0) == 0 or counts.subtract((l,)):
        result.append(l)
```

The tricky part here is the statement `counts.get(l, 0) == 0 or counts.subtract((l,))`. The `counts.subtract((l,))` means subtract 1 from the count of `l` and the return value of the expression is `None`, the fact that `None` is a boolean-like value (that evals to `False`) allows to use it a single `or` expression. So the above or will only be `True` when `counts.get(l, 0) == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
def remove_elems(l1, l2):
    removals = set(l2)
    result = []
    for elem in l1:
        if elem in removals:
            removals.remove(elem)
        else:
            result.append(elem)
    return result

l1 = [1,2,2,3]
l2 = [1,2]

print(remove_elems(l1, l2))  # -> [2, 3]
```